# How to make use of spare research budget?

Tags: research-process, professorship

I have a £1000 of funding that I can use for my research or teaching. I have bought a few books with it, but I have no other immediate necessity (conference trips etc). I do not like the budget to lapse (by the end of this July) and I am afraid I may have looked past some potential benefits I could have gained using the budget.

What are some possible ways for me to make use of this sum in this limited time?

Comment: Buy computers, stuff like that?

Comment: That's a very low sum. I would suggest to stock up on some consumables. What kind of research are you doing that you don't know how to spend money? Most researchers I know have more ideas for spending money than financial and/or administrative resources.

Comment: Are you sure it has to lapse?  Many funding agencies offer a "no-cost extension" which gives you more time to spend money already allocated.

Comment: What is your field?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am in the economics dept.

Comment: See if any students who you supervise would like to go to a conference?

Comment: Do you have some limitations on what cannot be charged to the grant ? I've seen some cases where buying computers were forbidden.

Comment: Society dues, if they need paying

Answer (score 1):

Spend forward (into 2018-2019) with opportunities related to the research which originally got funded.

Why not top up with a last-minute research trip, or a write-up trip completed and paid for by the end of the grant period?

Answer (score 0):

There's always a new version of some software you use. This is also the perfect time to learn how to use a software package. There's always something to be learned and always someone willing (to be paid) to teach it.

Comment: I can imagine hiring someone to teach a software package being very difficult, beaurocrattically.